# Автообновление комментариев

Tags: node.js, javascript

Возникла задача - обновить блок с комментариями на странице, хочется сделать как вконтакте. Чтоб обновление приходило после добавления другими пользователями автоматически. Варианты с функцией, которая будет через время обновлять не подходят из-за нагрузки. Есть идея сделать через node.js.

Не пойму, как найти пользователей на текущей странице? Как определить id страницы?

Comment: гуглите socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта.

1. Когда страница открылась, делаем ajax запрос на новые комментарии. Сервер при этом ответ не отсылает, а начинает ждать новых комментариев и держать коннект. Как только новые комментарии от других пользователей пришли на страницу, сервер отсылает их уже нашем пользователю. А браузер после получения комментариев снова делает запрос на новые комменты.
2. Использовать сокет. При загрузке страницы открывает к серверу веб-сокет. Нода, когда придут новые комменты, будет отправлять их в сокет, а браузер забирать и добавлять.